# Symfony2: fetch the result of raw sql query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to fetch some info from database using raw sql queries with doctrine-orm. However I get not output when it comes to results. Query itself seems to be fine since I've tested it directly on my database console. Where is the possible problem and how can I fetch data by sql query?

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
...
$queryCurrency = $entityManager->createNativeQuery('SELECT * FROM exchange_rates;', $rsm);
$queryCurrency->setParameter(1, 'romanb');

$dateCurrency = $queryCurrency->getResult();

$output->writeln($dateCurrency); //nothing appears here
```

Comment: Did you tried to pass entity name along with bundle instead of table name?

Comment: Yes. But is still not working for me.

Comment: You can use `createQuery()` to accomplish the same.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-nativequery-class

Comment: 1. Remove the trailing semicolon in the SQL statement - it's unnecessary
2. What does your ResultSetMapping object look like? Are you mapping to an Entity?
3. There are no parameters in your query so why are you setting a parameter?